# Changing Image in Powerpoint using Excel VBA Early Binding

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to change the pictures that are there in the existing Presentation.

one of the code is working but other is not.

Can you tell me the first one is not working?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Open_Access_Replace_Save()

Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application

ppt.Visible = msoCTrue

'To open Existing Powerpoint Presentation
Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set ppres = ppt.Presentations.Open("E:\ExcelPowerpoint\Opening Presentation and Acessing Shapes\Single Slide.pptx")

Dim pslide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set pslide = ppres.Slides(2)

'Image Change

'Attempt 1
Dim l As Single
Dim t As Single
Dim h As Single
Dim w As Single
Dim shap As PowerPoint.Shape

l = pslide.Shapes(8).Left
t = pslide.Shapes(8).Top
h = pslide.Shapes(8).Height
w = pslide.Shapes(8).Width
pslide.Shapes(8).Delete

'This is not working
Set pslide.Shapes(8) = 
pslide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Vinod\Desktop\news.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h)

'This is working
Set shap = pslide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Vinod\Desktop\news.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h)
```

Comment: Hi Vinod, can you be more specific? What exactely is not working? Which line causes an error? or what happens that is unexpected?

Comment: The last line in the above code is working...And line before that is not...

Answer (score 1):

Your code deletes the picture, then tries to replace it.

Here's a sub more suited to a real-life scenario, where you don't already know the shape number of the photo:

```
Sub ChangePictures()
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape, NewPic As Shape
  Dim pLeft!, pTop!, pWidth!, pHeight!

  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      If oShape.Type = msoPicture Then
        With oShape
          pLeft! = .Left
          pTop! = .Top
          pWidth! = .Width
          pHeight! = .Height
          .PickUp
          .Delete
        End With
        Set NewPic = oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture2(FileName:="C:\TimeIcon.png", LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=pLeft!, Top:=pTop!, Width:=pWidth!, Height:=pHeight!)
        NewPic.Apply
      End If
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```